# How can I control a Windows client from another client through a web server?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, sockets, signalr

**Summary**

I am trying to create a system in .net C# that is an IT tool to control Windows clients where ever they are in the world. The agent needs to work over https and control will be given to an admin console else where in the world through a proxy web server. An example of the types of control I require are command line, registry, file explorer and VNC.

When requested by the admin console the client needs to respond straight away (if it is online). I understand this requires some sort of persistent connection to the web server.

**Detail**

I am currently using a web server running WCF. The agent that runs on the client works well in that the client can tell the web server its status on a timer however I am struggling to know how the admin console can request the agent to give control of registry etc through the WCF connection. Does this require a new connection to be opened using a different technology?

I have found that there are technologies such as SignalR which looks very interesting and could help but it is designed to send information/messages that are <32KB which obviously won't work with remote tools such as registry etc.

It is very frustrating as I have seen others use such remote control technology such as Kaseya and Naverisk. What sort of methods are they using?

**Requirements**

The agent is not to allow any ports in so it has to make a connection to the web server via https ready to take requests from an admin console.

**Question**

Can someone please point me in the right direction of what technology can do this type of communication through a web server?

I only know .net but would be prepared to look into other technologies if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use websockets whereby the outbound connection from the agent is upgraded to a two way connection once connection is made. The admin console then may send messages through the socket. There are a number of websocket libraries for .NET which can assist and WCF NetHTTPSBinding can be used.

Alternatively, the Azure Service Bus Relay with WCF binding offered in Azure can do this - both parties establish an outbound connection and then send and receive message to each other.  This works more reliably when one end is in Azure, but using the relay with both ends outside of Azure also works.

Access to Windows Registry by a Windows application (e.g. Windows Service) running under the right security context (ACL) will be possible.